# static NSDateFormatter always nil

Tags: ios, cocoa, static, nsdateformatter

In my model object, I'm assigning a date like this:

```
static NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = nil;
if (nil == dateFormat) {
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
}

dateCreated = [dateFormat dateFromString:@"2013-03-04 09:16:41"];
```

What I'm seeing is that `dateFormat` is always `nil`; therefore, `dateCreated` is set to `nil`. Not sure how to go about debugging this...

Comment: why you want dateFormat as static?

Comment: Here is a good explanation of the `static` keyword: http://stackoverflow.com/a/572550/620197

Comment: I've read about reusing a static formatter ([example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4453550/iphone-sdk-best-practice-for-using-nsdateformatter-in-cellforrowatindexpath)). In my case, this NSDateFormatter would be recreated thousands of times, so the goal was to reduce that expenditure.

Comment: @davidm: This means your design is not good. Why to create a formatter in a method/loop and call it thousands of time. Search for better design.

Comment: @AnoopVaidya I don't agree; this is simply a singleton pattern, done locally and there is no reason to suspect the design is incorrect.

Comment: @davidm, NSDateFormatter is resource heavy thus reusing it is bad practice.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The issue is simply that you've introduced another non-`static` `dateFormat` variable inside the `if` statement.

Try this:

```
static NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = nil;
if (nil == dateFormat) {
    dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init]; // NOT NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = ...
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

reason for `NSDateFormatter` not nill is the `static` keyword in the start, `static` keyword initialize the `NSDateFormatter` nil only once and when you check the `NSDateFormatter` later in your code, it is never nil

Comment: it initialize the `NSDateFormatter` to nil only once and whenever later on in the app you try to access it, it will never be nil

Comment: I still don't understand what you mean.  That is not the issue the OP is having anyway; he's simply using 2 variables with the same name at different scopes...

Comment: i explained what static does in c or objectivc-c but  you have clarified in your answer about what is his problem, +1 for your answer